# "Breaking news" rolling view as in apples notification center

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How would you go about creating a rolling breaking news view, as you can see in apples notification center on the iphone (Where the stock is shown)?

Is there any open source examples of this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel`
```

MarqueeLabel is a functional equivalent to UILabel that adds a scrolling marquee effect when the text of the label outgrows the available width (for the given font size). All standard UILabel properties are available in MarqueeLabel and it behaves just like a UILabel.